# Gmail auto reply script- how to stop multiple replies?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail-api

I have a auto reply script to reply to evry email that i recived, with a attached file

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById('file_id').getAs('application/pdf')
function reply() {
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('new-mail');
  var messages = label.getThreads();
      for (let mess of messages) {
        if (mess.getMessageCount() == 1) {
           mess.reply('attached',{
           attachments:[file]
           });
  
          mess.removeLabel(label);
        }
          else mess.removeLabel(label)
      }
}
```

now, i want to reply to the sender only once a day, that meens that it won't send the auto reply message to senders that have already received it today
how i should do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) to save all the email addresses that you already replied to.

### Sample Code:

```
function initializeLogs(){
  //Get Script properties
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  scriptProperties.setProperty('email','');
}

function reply() {
  
  //Get Script properties
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var emailLogs = scriptProperties.getProperty('email');
  Logger.log(emailLogs);
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('new-mail');
  var messages = label.getThreads();
  
  for (let mess of messages) {
    if (mess.getMessageCount() == 1) {

      //get email address of the message sender
      var sender = mess.getMessages()[0].getFrom();

      if(!emailLogs.includes(sender)){
        Logger.log(sender);
        //sender not yet in the logs, send reply
        mess.reply('attached',{
          attachments:[file]
          });

        mess.removeLabel(label);

        //add sender to the logs
        scriptProperties.setProperty('email', emailLogs+sender)
      }
    }
      else mess.removeLabel(label)
  }
}
```

### Pre-requisite:

1. Run `initializeLogs()` once to initialize `email` key with an empty string.
2. Create a [Time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) to call `initializeLogs()` daily (which aims to reset your list of replied emails on a daily basis

[image]

[image]

### What it does?

1. As mentioned, `initializeLogs()` will create an `email` key with the value of an empty string `''` using [setProperty(key, value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties#setpropertykey,-value)
2. For `reply()`. First get the current email logs using [getProperty(key)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties#getpropertykey)
3. Get the sender of the email
4. Check if the sender already exist in the email logs string using [string.includes()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp). If user exist, do not send a reply
5. If user doesn't exist, send a reply and append the current sender's email address to the email logs.

Comment: Please let me know if you encountered some issues regarding the solution provided so i could update accordingly

Comment: wow! but let me understand, where is the 'initializeLogs()' need to run, in the same script or in another?

Comment: you can define the `initializeLogs()` function in the same script with your `reply()` then run it once in your apps script editor. Don't forget to create a time triggered event afterwards to automatically initialize your email list everyday

Comment: i want that the 'reply' function should run every minut, so i use triger for every minut but i want the log should be deleted only once per day. so, if its runing in the same script the property will be started again every minut? no? (sorry for my english)

Comment: No. you can create multiple trigger in the same script. You can refer to the configuration i shared in the answer. initializeLogs() was set to trigger on a `Day timer` every `midnight to 1am`. Therefore, your script will have 2 triggers. 1 for your reply() and another for your initializeLogs()

Comment: Glad to hear that. By the way, If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: now when thinking about them... ` initializeLogs()` makes it to delete the properties not matter when the sender sends this message, and i want that the sender should not get a reply in the next 24 hours after the first message, every sender in his 24 hour. its there any way to do it?

Comment: oh that's quite complicated since you need to record the time when the first reply to a sender was done. But it is possible if you record the data in google sheets. But are you really sure you want them to prevent receiving reply emails for 24hrs? rather than on a daily basis?

Comment: Based on my personal opinion, it is best to reset it on a daily basis rather than after 24hrs

Comment: no, i'm not really sure... i think its too complicated for me at this moment. thanks anyway (but is there a place to read about it anywhere? maybe for the future)

Comment: Here's a quick [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ulFKsrpxi8&list=PLv9Pf9aNgemv62NNC5bXLR0CzeaIj5bcw&index=3) for reading and writing into sheets. For the timestamp you can search that here in stackoverflow. Or probably you can post another question regarding that on a new thread if you have a hard time looking for references